# How can I trace a functional expression's evaluation visually?

Tags: dynamic, functional-style, visualization, debugging, meta-programming

Ok, so the goal is to visualize the execution of this expression

```
foo /@ {3 + 1, bar /@ {1 + 2, {4 + 7}}}
```

in the following fashion using nested rectangles with mouseover highlighting and tooltips that show the highlighted subexpression's values.

[image]

Ok, that works and looks great, but the code is ugly:

```
Clear[foo, bar];
expr = MapAll[h1, 
   Unevaluated[foo /@ {3 + 1, bar /@ {1 + 2, {4 + 7}}}], 
   Heads -> True];

expr = expr //. h1[x_] :> h2[HoldForm[x], h3[x]];

expr = expr //. 
   h2[x_, y_] :> 
    Mouseover[
     Tooltip[Framed[x, Background -> White, FrameMargins -> 10, 
       RoundingRadius -> 10], y], 
     Tooltip[Framed[x, Background -> Hue[0.6, 1, 1, 0.1], 
       FrameMargins -> 10, RoundingRadius -> 10], y]];

Cleanh2[x___] := 
 Module[{xx = {x}}, 
  xx = xx //. {Framed[a_] :> a, Tooltip[b_, c_] :> c, 
     Verbatim[HoldForm][d__] :> d, Mouseover[e_, f_] :> e};
  Sequence @@ xx]

expr = expr //. h3 -> Cleanh2;

MouseAppearance[
 Magnify[Dynamic[Evaluate[expr] //. Verbatim[HoldForm][d___] :> d], 
  1], "+"]
```

and quickly breaks:

```
expr = MapAll[h1, 
   Unevaluated[
    Module[{t = RandomInteger[1, 10]}, 
     MapThread[f, {t, RotateLeft[t] + RotateRight[t]}]]], 
   Heads -> True];

expr = expr //. h1[x_] :> h2[HoldForm[x], h3[x]];

expr = expr //. 
   h2[x_, y_] :> 
    Mouseover[
     Tooltip[Framed[x, Background -> White, FrameMargins -> 10, 
       RoundingRadius -> 10], y], 
     Tooltip[Framed[x, Background -> Hue[0.6, 1, 1, 0.1], 
       FrameMargins -> 10, RoundingRadius -> 10], y]];

expr = expr //. h3 -> Cleanh2;
MouseAppearance[
 Magnify[Dynamic[Evaluate[expr] //. Verbatim[HoldForm][d___] :> d], 
  1], "+"]
```

How can I do this cleanly in a general fashion? There must be a way...

Comment: Strongly related: "[The clearest way to represent Mathematica's evaluation sequence.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5459735/590388)"

Comment: You don't really visualize evaluation, it seems - just a structure of your unevaluated expression. You may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459735/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/5527117#5527117) out.

Comment: This question was inspired by Bret Victor's approach (http://vimeo.com/36579366) to debugging code visually.

Comment: @Leonif Shifrin Note the tooltips have the evaluation in them. I like this TracePrint function, though it seems ugly and not really what I'm going for.

Comment: @Mike I see, I missed that.

Comment: @Mike no going for *how*?  Appearance?  I think it can be modified.

Comment: Okay, I took another look at both and I think I understand your objection.  I suspect that implementing what you want for all code will be challenging.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard agreed

Comment: The general problem with this approach is that it will mess up scoping and generally the evaluation process, because you can not take pieces of code, evaluate them separately, and expect that this would correspond to the original evaluation, unless your code is completely referentially transparent and free of side effects. The approach based on `Trace` works because nothing is evaluated there, and the output of `Trace` reflects the actual evaluation process. Other approach would be one of traditional debuggers. But for that, you need execution context. Probably doable, but lots of work.

Comment: On a philosophical note, the tool you want is fancy but hardly practical, at least to me. What I value in debugging tools is that they are selective, so that they show *only* parts I want to look at, and help me quickly filter out the rest. So, to me, a good debugger is a good filter in the first place, allowing me to skip the stuff I don't really want to see. So, at least in the form you want it currently, your tool will be wasteful (both for computer and for you, because you will have to go through all these fancy tooltips to find the place you want), and IMO for no good reason.

Comment: @Leonid Would you write up your comments as an answer for this unanswered question? I think it correctly summarizes the issues one would encounter tackling this Q and also gives an explanation on why this question wasn't answered so far ("lots of work"). Perhaps you can reuse some of your concerns from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40159/89).

Comment: @IstvánZachar Actually, having reread the question, I think that such an answer would not do it justice. I am pretty sure that there *is* some way to visualize an execution of a functional program, perhaps bringing the linked answer of WReach to the next level, and / or adding some stuff to it. The answer I could compile from these comments would be rather on the negative side, though. But, this is a good question worth returning to. My personal problem is a lack of time, but may be I will set a bounty on this one. Right now gtg, but thanks for reminding me about it.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thanks for keep this on your radar!

Comment: @M.R. Thanks for reminding. I  certainly do keep this in mind, also because I am interested in this too. But I am currently in the same situation as I was then, and free time is as elusive now as it was then, 2 years ago.

Comment: If it is required only for the purpose of debugging a code, please take the output of the variables at the critical locations of the code and debug it rather than converting the code into graphical mode and cross check.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of ExpressionTree and TreeFold.

```
ExpressionTree[Unevaluated[foo /@ {3 + 1, bar /@ {1 + 2, {4 + 7}}}]]
```

ExpressionTree has some nice options, so this might be useful:

```
ExpressionTree[Unevaluated[foo /@ {3 + 1, bar /@ {1 + 2, {4 + 7}}}], "Arguments"]
```

But then, if you use the example from the documenation of TreeForm, you can do this, which is close to the form in the original post:

```
TreeFold[
  {Framed[Row[{#, Row[#2, " "]}]] &, Framed}, 
  ExpressionTree[Unevaluated[foo /@ {3 + 1, bar /@ {1 + 2, {4 + 7}}}]]]
```

Comment: Can you make this interactive?

Comment: What part of it do you want to make interactive? You might be interested in TraceDialog, which interactively steps through evaluation of an expression. Or TracePrint that will just print out each step. If you want the tooltips, I assume it would work to add Tooltip at the desired places in the functions passed to TreeFold, but I haven't tried it.